# Changing MKAnnotation view without removing the MKAnnotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a callout on an MKAnnotation. The accessory on the callout should, when tapped, change the MKAnnotationView's image. Is there a way to change this, without recreating the MKAnnotation? The reason I ask is that I would like to change the image, **without** removing the callout. But obviously, the callout gets removed when I remove the annotation. So how do I simply **change** the image, so that the callout does not get removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MKMapViewDelegate has the methods `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` and `mapView:didDeselectAnnotationView:`. You are passed the MKAnnotationView here, and you can modify it here. Put code like this in your delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinImage.png"];
}
```